# Show saved files in mvc with dot net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, iformfile

I'm trying to upload multiple files using `IFormFile`.. this is my html

```
<input type="file" asp-for="lstAttachments" accept="application/pdf,application" multiple/>
```

where `lstAttachments` is a collection of `IFormFile`

```
public IEnumerable<IFormFile> lstAttachments { get; set; }
```

I'm saving files to some folder and then path of folder to database table. 
That is working perfectly fine.

```
var filePath = "" ;
Guid guid;
List<userattachmentsdetail> attachmentsToInsert = new List<userattachmentsdetail>();
userattachmentsdetail newAttachment;
foreach (var file in userDetail.lstAttachments)
{
         guid = Guid.NewGuid();
         filePath = hostingEnv.WebRootPath + $@"\uploadedFiles" + $@"\{guid}_{file.FileName}";

        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            file.CopyTo(fs);
            fs.Flush();
        }

        newAttachment = new userattachmentsdetail();

        newAttachment.FileName = file.FileName;
        newAttachment.FilePath = filePath;
        attachmentsToInsert.Add(newAttachment);

   }
```

In edit mode, I'm getting name and path from that table and trying to load files

This is my query to get file path data from table

```
Select FileName, FilePath from userattachmentsdetail uad
```

And here I'm storing data to list

```
List<userattachmentsdetail> lstFiles = grid.Read<UserFiles>().ToList();
```

`lstFiles` contain all files but now I'm stuck that how to convert/ copy this data to `IFormFile` collection (lstAttachments).

**Edit** Files content can be pdf, text or docx.

Comment: what do the files look like? what does IFormFile look like?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you??

Comment: What is the content of the files, and post your code for IFormFile, and it's implementation. There's nowhere near enough information in this question to even start helping

Comment: @Alex Files can be of pdf, docx or plain text.

Comment: You cannot set the value of a file input for security reasons. The only way it can be set is by the user selecting a file in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

**IFormFile**

> Represents a file sent with the HttpRequest.

It's only ever meant to represent an inbound file.

For your 'edit' functionality, you just need to overwrite the file you have saved, if it is changed by the end user.